# Most efficient way to set individual pixels WinAPI C++

Tags: c++, winapi

**Introduction:**
Thank you for reading this. I am a relative newbie at C++ and very new to WinAPI.

**Objective:**
I am trying to develop a 2D game (diving in the deep end I know). I would like to make a window (in WinAPI) with moving images (to make up the background and sprites etc) however I would like to use a custom image format (similar to a bump map in CGI) that requires reactive textures.

**Question**:
What would be the most efficient (processing wise) method to set individual pixels within a window? (In C++ with WinAPI)

**Sidenote:**
If it would be impossible to set pixels efficiently enough using C++ alone I would be happy to learn Assembly.

**End:**
Thank you for your time and knowledge.

Comment: Perhaps you should start with a more mainstream method like SFML or SDL before you dive into pushing pixels the very hard and inefficient way? Whatever those "reactive textures" are could very probably be implemented using GPU shaders.

Comment: what is the meaning of "most efficient" exactly? Define that first then measure. Pondering about it before you have some code is futile.

Comment: @idclev463035818 I don't know a crazy amount about how code is efficient but for example, I mean you wouldn't use "Bitblt" to code a game because it is too inefficient

Comment: Stop worrying about efficiency up front. You have to learn C++ first. Get something working first, then use that experience to build something better.

Comment: @Ash That you want to work with individual pixels and think BitBlt is slower than that suggests you have some significant misunderstandings. In all honesty you aren't ready to dive in to this project yet. You need to master the basics first. There are no shortcuts.

Comment: If you don't want to use Bitblt then the Windows API has nothing for you.  You want DirectX or something like that.

Comment: The most efficient way is to not use CPU for that. Get an API that's GPU-accelerated (OpenGL, DirectX, etc).

Answer (score 3):

Create an in-memory bitmap with the desired pixel dimensions.  Draw your pixels to that bitmap as needed.  Whenever 1 or more pixels change, call `InvalidateRect()` to signal to the OS that the window needs a repaint.  Whenever  the window receives a `WM_PAINT` message for any reason, simply `BitBlt()`/`StretchBlt()` the current bitmap (or, at least, just the portion of the bitmap corresponding to the current clipping region reported by `GetClipBox()` or `GetClipRgn()`) onto the `HDC` returned by `BeginPaint()`.

Alternatively, create your window with the `WS_EX_LAYERED` extended window style, and then create a bitmap with the same dimensions, and use `UpdateLayeredWindow()` to assign the latest bitmap directly to the window whenever the bitmap's pixels change.  No need to handle `WM_PAINT` in that scenario.  See [Layered Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#layered-windows) for more details.

Comment: cheers, I'll definitely give this a shot.